# SQL Aggregate Function Written 2 Different Ways

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the difference between the following:

```
1) select col_1 = max(col_1)
```

AND

```
2) select max(col_1) as col_1
```

Are they the same just written two different ways?

Comment: On SQL Server these should behave identically.  Note that the first version would probably not run on most other databases, though.  So, stick with the second version if you ever plan to port your code to another database.

Comment: No difference. You can add `select max(col_1) col_1` to your collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yup, just a different way to write. no functional difference, same results and always the same query plan as far as I've seen. I rarely write with the col1 = max(col1), only when it adds readability for later troubleshooting or documentation.